# Запрос по JDBC только для одного потока

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm, websphere

Есть два потока, которые обращаются к одному классу, который делает запрос в БД. Мне необходимо сделать так, что бы они физически не могли сделать запрос одновременно.

P.S. эти потоки настолько независимы, что они съехали от родителей в первые месяцы после рождения. Друг друга они не видят и никогда не увидят. Единственное что их связывает, это запрос в ДБ. Мне не нужно решение - мне необходима подсказка или же ссылка на пример, документацию или что-то еще.

Эти потоки это ноды IIB
Простите если сразу не написал
По сути есть две разные ноды которые вызывают java ноду

Comment: синхронизируйте метод где выполняется запрос.

Comment: Или используйте транзакции с должным уровнем изоляции.

Comment: Можно настроить "однопоточный" connection pool.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, спасибо, это отличный вариант для решения ОТМЕЧАЮ СВОЙ ОТВЕТ КАК ПРАВЕЛЬНЫЙ, ПОСКОЛЬКУ ВАШ КОММЕНТАРИЙ НЕЛЬЗЯ ОТМЕТИТЬ